# RPM build correctly setting Provides on openSUSE, but not Fedora

Tags: rpm-spec

I have an RPM specfile for MakeMKV which is uploaded to OBS to build packages for Fedora and openSUSE. The specfile is the same between both distributions, but only openSUSE correctly adds the built libraries to the build packages Provides section, causing package installation to fail on Fedora.

I have tried to place all of the files in a single package, but this still doesn't allow installation on Fedora. openSUSE detects the libraries if they are all placed into the same package or packaged individually.

Here is my specfile:

```
Name: makemkv
Version: 1.9.10
Release: 0
Summary: DVD and Blu-ray to MKV converter and network streamer
License: SUSE-NonFree
Group: Productivity/Multimedia/Other
Url: http://www.makemkv.com
Source0: %name-oss-%version.tar.gz
Source1: %name-bin-%version.tar.gz
BuildRequires: pkgconfig(zlib) pkgconfig(openssl) pkgconfig(expat) pkgconfig(libavcodec) pkgconfig(libavutil)
%if 0%{?centos} || 0%{?fedora} || 0%{?rhel} || 0%{?scientificlinux}
BuildRequires: pkgconfig
%endif
%if 0%{?centos} || 0%{?rhel} || 0%{?scientificlinux}
BuildRequires: libqt4-devel
%endif
%if 0%{?fedora}
BuildRequires: qt5-qtbase-devel
%endif
%if 0%{?suse_version}
BuildRequires: pkg-config libqt5-qtbase-devel update-desktop-files
%endif

%description
MakeMKV is your one-click solution to convert video that you own into free and patents-unencumbered format that can be played everywhere. MakeMKV is a format converter, otherwise called "transcoder". It converts the video clips from proprietary (and usually encrypted) disc into a set of MKV files, preserving most information but not changing it in any way. The MKV format can store multiple video/audio tracks with all meta-information and preserve chapters. There are many players that can play MKV files nearly on all platforms, and there are tools to convert MKV files to many formats, including DVD and Blu-ray discs.

Additionally MakeMKV can instantly stream decrypted video without intermediate conversion to wide range of players, so you may watch Blu-ray and DVD discs with your favorite player on your favorite OS or on your favorite device.

%package -n libdriveio0
Summary: DVD and Blu-ray to MKV converter and network streamer

%description -n libdriveio0
MakeMKV is your one-click solution to convert video that you own into free and patents-unencumbered format that can be played everywhere. MakeMKV is a format converter, otherwise called "transcoder". It converts the video clips from proprietary (and usually encrypted) disc into a set of MKV files, preserving most information but not changing it in any way. The MKV format can store multiple video/audio tracks with all meta-information and preserve chapters. There are many players that can play MKV files nearly on all platforms, and there are tools to convert MKV files to many formats, including DVD and Blu-ray discs.

Additionally MakeMKV can instantly stream decrypted video without intermediate conversion to wide range of players, so you may watch Blu-ray and DVD discs with your favorite player on your favorite OS or on your favorite device.

%package -n libmakemkv1
Summary: DVD and Blu-ray to MKV converter and network streamer

%description -n libmakemkv1
MakeMKV is your one-click solution to convert video that you own into free and patents-unencumbered format that can be played everywhere. MakeMKV is a format converter, otherwise called "transcoder". It converts the video clips from proprietary (and usually encrypted) disc into a set of MKV files, preserving most information but not changing it in any way. The MKV format can store multiple video/audio tracks with all meta-information and preserve chapters. There are many players that can play MKV files nearly on all platforms, and there are tools to convert MKV files to many formats, including DVD and Blu-ray discs.

Additionally MakeMKV can instantly stream decrypted video without intermediate conversion to wide range of players, so you may watch Blu-ray and DVD discs with your favorite player on your favorite OS or on your favorite device.

%package -n libmmbd0
Summary: DVD and Blu-ray to MKV converter and network streamer

%description -n libmmbd0
MakeMKV is your one-click solution to convert video that you own into free and patents-unencumbered format that can be played everywhere. MakeMKV is a format converter, otherwise called "transcoder". It converts the video clips from proprietary (and usually encrypted) disc into a set of MKV files, preserving most information but not changing it in any way. The MKV format can store multiple video/audio tracks with all meta-information and preserve chapters. There are many players that can play MKV files nearly on all platforms, and there are tools to convert MKV files to many formats, including DVD and Blu-ray discs.

Additionally MakeMKV can instantly stream decrypted video without intermediate conversion to wide range of players, so you may watch Blu-ray and DVD discs with your favorite player on your favorite OS or on your favorite device.

%prep
tar xf %{SOURCE0}
tar xf %{SOURCE1}

%build
cd %{name}-oss-%{version}
%configure
make %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
cd %{name}-oss-%{version}
make install DESTDIR=%buildroot
%if 0%{?suse_version}
%suse_update_desktop_file -r makemkv
%suse_update_desktop_file -c makemkv MakeMKV "DVD and Blu-ray to MKV converter and network streamer" makemkv makemkv AudioVideo AudioVideoEditing
%endif

cd ../%{name}-bin-%{version}
mkdir tmp
echo accepted > tmp/eula_accepted
make install DESTDIR=%buildroot

%if "/usr/lib" != "%_libdir"
mv %buildroot/usr/lib/ %buildroot/%_libdir
%endif

%post -n libdriveio0 -p /sbin/ldconfig
%postun -n libdriveio0 -p /sbin/ldconfig
%post -n libmakemkv1 -p /sbin/ldconfig
%postun -n libmakemkv1 -p /sbin/ldconfig
%post -n libmmbd0 -p /sbin/ldconfig
%postun -n libmmbd0 -p /sbin/ldconfig

%files
%defattr(-,root,root)
#oss
%dir /usr/share/icons/hicolor
%dir /usr/share/icons/hicolor/*
%dir /usr/share/icons/hicolor/*/apps
/%_bindir/makemkv
/usr/share/applications/makemkv.desktop
/usr/share/icons/hicolor/*/apps/makemkv.png
#bin
/%_bindir/makemkvcon
/%_bindir/mmdtsdec
/usr/share/MakeMKV/

%files -n libdriveio0
%defattr(-,root,root)
/%_libdir/libdriveio.so.0

%files -n libmakemkv1
%defattr(-,root,root)
/%_libdir/libmakemkv.so.1

%files -n libmmbd0
%defattr(-,root,root)
/%_libdir/libmmbd.so.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions on the library were not properly set. Running

```
chmod 755 %buildroot/%_libdir/lib*.so*
```

fixed this and then Fedora properly set the Provides field.